# Specific font stopped working in Photoshop/Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, font-management, creative-cloud

**The problem:**

I downloaded a free font called Voyager from a Behance user and installed it to my computer. I used the font in Photoshop to create a `.psd` file and everything worked as expected.

The next day, problems arose when I tried to edit the `.psd`. The font shows up and PS does *not* give me any missing font errors. I can resize, italicize, "fake bold", adjust kerning/tracking, etc. etc. without any font substitution. When I use the type tool to actually try to change the characters, PS changes the font to Myriad Pro and won't use the Voyager font. If I try to use the dropdown to change to Voyager manually, the dropdown either switches back to Myriad Pro or just shows up blank.

- [Here's the Behance
  page](https://www.behance.net/gallery/VGER-Grotesque/6636573)
- [Here's the download page](http://fontm.com/vger-grotesque-font/)

**Things I've tried:**

- Disabled PS font preview
- Cleared PS font cache
- Uninstalled/reinstalled the font multiple times

If I hadn't been able to use it at all, I wouldn't be so stumped. But the fact that it allowed me to use it normally and just stopped working is very confusing.

Comment: You basically get what you pay for.... :)

Comment: I don't have any problem with paying for fonts. This one was offered by the creator for free and I liked the style of it. Thankfully, GoofyMonkey was able to help me find the solution.

Comment: I think you should consult the developer of the font..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded the font and I'm getting some really odd results too. It seems to work fine when you type in caps, but when you switch to lowercase letters it defaults back to myriad. The font table doesn't include any lowercase letters and it looks like Photoshop is doing some odd substitutions because of that.

Bad or incomplete font.

Comment: You're right! I didn't even notice that. Typing in all caps appears to be the solution. I just didn't see any comments on the Behance page asking about these issues so I assumed it was me. Thanks for your help.